# Codename One simulator show only middle of picture

Tags: image, codenameone

I am using below code to get image from url. In the simulator only the middle center of the picture is shown in correct height but image is stretched, looks like it takes 1/3 of the original picture from center height. How can I get the full picture in the simulator?

```
EncodedImage placeholder = EncodedImage.createFromImage(Image.createImage(100, 100, 0xf0f00000), false);
URLImage img = URLImage.createToStorage(placeholder, "profilbillede.jpg", URL, URLImage.RESIZE_SCALE);
img.fetch();

                    //border container
Container ct = new Container(new BorderLayout());
ct.add(BorderLayout.NORTH, new Label(""))
      .add(BorderLayout.WEST, new Label(""))
      .add(BorderLayout.EAST, new Label(""))
      .add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, new Label(""));
ScaleImageLabel picture = new ScaleImageLabel(img);
ct.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, picture);
home.add(ct);
```

Comment: Besides the comment from Diamond you can check if the scale operation is what changed the image or the layout. You can open the file in the .cn1 directory and inspect the resulting image after scaling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in CreatetoStorage don't use file extension

Answer (score 2):

Your image will be download and created according to the size of your placeholder image. In this case, 100 x 100px. I will suggest you use the device with to scale the image properly by changing your placeholder declaration line to:

```
EncodedImage placeholder = EncodedImage.createFromImage(Image.createImage(CN.getDisplayWidth(), CN.getDisplayWidth(), 0xf0f00000), false); //or half of the screen width by dividing CN.getDisplayWidth() to 2
```

I will also suggest you use `URLImage.RESIZE_SCALE_TO_FILL` in place of `URLImage.RESIZE_SCALE` in your `URLImage` method.

The previously cached images will be used until its cleared. To clear them, go to your user home folder and look for `.cn1` folder. On Windows, it's at `C:\Users\UserName`.

Comment: Thx, tried the changes but got the same result though.

Comment: Try to use `Label` instead of `ScaleImageLabel`

Comment: Label gives same result

Comment: hmmmm very strange. I removed the .jpg from profilbillede.jpg in URLImage creation and now it shows full picture.......

Comment: Oh, I forgot to tell you to delete cached images, check my updated answer.